# Apostrophe replacement in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have in a column names(notes) as

Notes:

> John's Table

```
Smith's Window
```

Column contains an apostrophe in it. I am trying to run 2 queries.

1. Select query to get the column entries that have apostrophe.
2. Update those with apostrophe with empty string ie.John's Table replace to John Table

> select notes from table1 where notes like ' '% ';

I get a syntax error , any help will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the apostrophe with a backslash;

```
select notes from table1 where notes like '%\'%';
```

And to update, use [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE table1 SET notes = REPLACE(notes, '\'', '');
```

Comment: +1 but I'd add a leading % wildcard to the search as well. `...notes like '%\'%';` and I'd add the same WHERE clause to the UPDATE.

Comment: Note this does not produce the example results, i.e. `Johns Table` vs `John Table`. Unless the OP has a typo...

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I assume that to be a typo in the OP since the instructions are _Update those with apostrophe with empty string_

Comment: +1 then for a more complete answer. With the caveat that two single quotes equal one literal single quote as an alternative escaping method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
select notes from table1 where notes like "'%";
```